# Cloud Firestore Node SDK - transaction.getAll is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

The transaction .getAll method does not work as [documented](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.11.x/Transaction#getAll).  I have copied and pasted the code from the given Example and it fails with an error.

### Transaction.getAll

Retrieves multiple documents from Firestore. Holds a pessimistic lock on all returned documents.

### The error

```
(node:24009) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: transaction.getAll is not a function
```

### My code

This copied straight from the documentation and the initialisation header added.

```
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = process.env.MY_CREDENTIALS;

firebase.initializeApp({
    credential: firebase.credential.cert(JSON.parse(serviceAccount))
});

const firestore = firebase.firestore();

let firstDoc = firestore.doc('col/doc1');
let secondDoc = firestore.doc('col/doc2');
let resultDoc = firestore.doc('col/doc2');

firestore.runTransaction(transaction => {
  return transaction.getAll(firstDoc, secondDoc).then(docs => {
    transaction.set(resultDoc, {
      sum: docs[1].get('count') + docs[2].get('count')
    });
  });
});
```

## Update since release of Firebase Admin Node.js SDK 5.9.1

This supports v12 of the Firestore Node.js client, which includes commits for transaction.getAll

### Testing

I removed the node_modules directory and all dependencies from package.json, then ran the following...

#### Package installation

```
$ npm install --save firebase-admin@5.9.1

> grpc@1.7.3 install /home/jason/Downloads/projects/testing/node_modules/grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

[grpc] Success: "/home/jason/Downloads/projects/testing/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" is installed via remote

> protobufjs@6.8.6 postinstall /home/jason/Downloads/projects/testing/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/protobufjs
> node scripts/postinstall


> protobufjs@6.8.6 postinstall /home/jason/Downloads/projects/testing/node_modules/google-proto-files/node_modules/protobufjs
> node scripts/postinstall

npm WARN testing@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN testing@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ firebase-admin@5.9.1
added 358 packages in 42.265s
```

#### Testing the code

```
(xenial)jason@localhost:~/Downloads/projects/testing$ node testTransactionGetAll.js 
(node:22273) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
(node:22273) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: This looks like a bug, either in documentation or in the implementation.  Feel free to file a bug.  I already filed one internally with the team.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Thanks for confirming that Doug.  I've raised a support ticket.  As this is a bug, rather than a coding query, should I delete this SO question?

Comment: No, someone else may have this question later before the problem is resolved.  Then they'll know what to do.  When it's fixed, there can be a final answer to your question.

Comment: I think this is fixed in the latest Firestore client: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/releases/tag/v0.12.0. Admin SDK will start using this version from the next release.

Comment: Thanks, Hiranya.  The Firebase Admin Node.js SDK version 5.9.1 (released 28th Feb 2018) upgraded the Cloud Firestore client to 0.12.0.  I'll test this and report back

Comment: Edited: This might be an npm issue on my device.....`npm install --save firebase-admin@5.9.1` returns an EINTEGRITY "integrity checksum failed" error .  Then it installs a stale version

Comment: I've updated the question with the update since installing 5.9.1

Comment: I found a bug in the documentation.  I'll send feedback.  All fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Fixed

`transaction.getAll` has been added to v0.12.x of the [Google Cloud Firestore Node.js Client](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.12.x/)  This update has been added to the [Firebase Admin Node.js SDK v5.9.1](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node)

However, the sample code in the documentation is incorrect.  The following line should be changed to:

```
sum: docs[0].get('count') + docs[1].get('count')
```

*Previously, it referenced `doc[2]`, which doesn't exist*